# Are nail pops in drywall a sign of structural concerns?

Tags: drywall, foundation, structural, nails

I’ve been noticing more and more mail pops throughout our home. Not sure if they are actually “ongoing” or I just notice them more. I see a lot like the picture below where the nail isn’t protruding out of the wall yet but you can see it bulging. Our home was built in 1938 and has had multiple additions. We live in an area with heavy freeze/thaw cycles. Exterior is mostly wood with large brick chimneys.. if that helps. In one room (newest addition - possibly late 60’s) is where there are the most. There are maybe 20 or so in the entire room with only one single “nail” able to be physically seen popping from the ceiling. There is an entire row of the wall that meets the ceiling where 5 or 6 have popped in a row. The rest of the home are scattered… maybe 2 or 3 near some windowsills or so (less than 15 or so in the rest of the house)

My question is… when do these become a problem and less cosmetic? Are there structural issues we need to be concerned about?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Would you not worry then and just let them be? Why is it a given the home has structural issues?

Comment: very few renovations are done up to the same structural engineering standard as the original build. Particularly if there are no permits or if you live in a smaller community where the building department inspector has beers with the contractors on the weekends. It’s very common and results in cut corners and poor quality

Comment: Drywall pops are not indicative of structural issues.  Drywall is not a structural material.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger it certainly can be. Anyway nail pops aren’t usually as structurally significant as cracks.

Comment: OTOH, @RibaldEddie sometimes renovations are done to modern code and are _far_ superior to work done 100 years ago.

Comment: @FreeMan yes sometimes

Comment: @FreshCodemonger https://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/fplrp/fplrp439.pdf

Comment: @FreshCodemonger nail pops can be a sign of racking

Comment: Nail pops can also be caused by the inside temperature having two large a variation. I used to work for a friend and he would turn the heat off when not rented until a big temp swing caused a lot of damage. I would be concerned if in a specific area but not so much a few here and there.

Comment: @RibaldEddie - I agree that drywall can contribute to structural strength but it isn't depended on or part of the structural design of the building.  Drywall nail pops or screw standoffs are extremely common.  Framing dries and shrinks, someone leans hard against a piece of drywall and the drywall is pushed back to the framing - some of the nails / screws are now 1/16" proud of the drywall surface.  Unless you are building in the desert and your wood stayed kiln dry for the whole construction period you'll have nail pops.

Comment: It sounds like the only answer we can give is "maybe, but not likely enough to worry about"?

Comment: Personally, I'm used to seeing plasterboard affixed with screws rather than nails. Screws don't pop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to safely eliminate all the bumps try this: use a dimpler bit on your screw gun to put a drywall screw about 2 inches from each nail head, in line with the stud. Be sure the screw heads are recessed properly. Then take a hammer and pound each nail head to make a small recess also. Scrape away any loose bits of old plaster, then apply drywall compound to all the double dimples. Sand, prime, and paint. Each screw secures the drywall and the old nails will stay in place.

Comment: "Then take a hammer and pound each nail head to make a small recess also." Why would you suggest the prolonging of this issue? If you're patching holes anyways then just remove the nails.

Comment: Too much unnecessary work and bigger gouges to fill. With the screw pulling the drywall tight to the stud, the old nail is not going anywhere.

Comment: You are aware of the root cause of nail pops, right?